# How to print bowtie in java?

Tags: java, loops

How to make this pattern if input N = 5 Output :

```
*    *
**  **
******
**  **
*    *
```

Here's my code

```
for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
            if ((j > i && j < n - i) || (j > (n-i) && j < i && i > n))
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The result is like this:

```
*    *
**  **
******
******
******
******
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Please send text, not images of text.

Comment: @Aplet123 If you make pictures of text visible and then ask for text instead of pictures of text you send mixed signals. Your chances at getting through are better if you only ask for text.

Comment: @Yunnosch While I (and I'm sure many other people) prefer text over images, I don't see the point in not improving the readability of the question for those who want to answer.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Also  'j > (n-i) && j < i && i > n' will always be false.

Answer (score 2):

You have used OR `||` to combine the upper down-pointing triangle of " " and the lower up-pointing triangle of " ". Good idea.

You describe the upper triangle as `(j > i && j < n - i)`, that is correct.

However, you describe the lower triangle as `(j > (n-i) && j < i && i > n)`.
That is where the problem is. The `i > n` is never true for `i` from 0 to `n` as in your outer loop construct. In order to describe the lower half of the pattern, you should have used `i>n/2`. You could have however dropped that part of the condition altogether, because the counter comparisons in the first part would only apply in the lower half anyway.
So `(j > (n-i) && j < i)`.

That gets you:

```
*    *
**  **
******
******
**  **
```

By the way, `n` lines, not `n+1` lines in the outer loop.

As you can see, the lower triangle of " " is much too small. Both, to the right side and to the left side.
So you need to make your conditions more generous, i.e. "lower-equal" and "higher-equal" instead of "lower" and "higher". In code `(j >= (n-i) && j <= i)`.

Putting it together:

```java
public class Main {
    static final int n = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // only n lines
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n+1; j++) {
                if ((j > i && j < n - i) ||
                    (j >= (n-i) && j <= i)) // more generous and no second condition
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is very similar to your attempt and gets you the desired

```
*    *
**  **
******
**  **
*    *
```

Comment: @ShashSinha I really accept your answer as your own work. I confirm that I do not consider it copied from mine. The time difference of posting is too small and the (small) differences look enough like separatly conceived. Feel free to undelete your question.

Comment: I didn't see your answer. And it has a lot better explanation.

Comment: @ShashSinha Of course not. It obviously appeared while you were editing yours. I mean no cynicism or sarcasm. Let's have a friendly race for upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Your existing attempt is actually really close here is a working version which fixes the second condition (that in your current attempt would always be false):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printBowtie(5);
    }

    private static void printBowtie(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
                if ((j > i && j < n - i) || (j >= n - i && j <= i)) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
*    *
**  **
******
**  **
*    *
```

**Relevant diff**:

```
     private static void printBowtie(int n) {
-        for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
+        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
-                if ((j > i && j < n - i) || (j > (n - i) && j < i && i > n)) {
+                if ((j > i && j < n - i) || (j >= n - i && j <= i)) {
```

Comment: I can see we were editing/creating our answers practically at the same time. That happens. Good luck in the race.

Comment: Wait is my condition the same as yours exactly?

Comment: Oh hey. I got you to 10k. My pleasure.

Comment: I like the diffing. It illustrates what is also a goal in my answer, to stay close to OPs approach.

Comment: Basically, when I ran OP's code I noticed the top half was correct so I just inverted the condition for the bottom half with some trial and error to get it to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it greatly by putting the common code in a method as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    static final int LINES = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Upper half
        for (int line = 1; line <= LINES / 2 + 1; line++) {
            print(line);
        }

        // Lower half
        for (int line = LINES / 2; line >= 1; line--) {
            print(line);
        }
    }

    static void print(int line) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= line; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= LINES - 2 * line + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= line; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
*    *
**  **
******
**  **
*    *
```